# Getting return type of a callback function

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, decltype

I am implementing a trivial profile function:

```
template <typename T>
typename T::return_type ProfilerRun(T&& func, const std::string& routine_name = "unknown" )
{
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::microseconds;
    using std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using std::cerr;
    using std::endl;
#ifdef SELF_PROFILING
    steady_clock::time_point t_begin = steady_clock::now();
#endif
    func();
#ifdef SELF_PROFILING
    steady_clock::time_point t_end = steady_clock::now();
    cerr << "Function " << routine_name << " duration: " <<
         duration_cast<microseconds>( t_end - t_begin ).count() <<
         " microseconds." << endl;
#endif
}
```

This works perfectly with `std::bind(&Class::function, class_object, param1, param2, ...)`, but it won't work with raw function pointers since they do not have `T::result_type` property. I have also thought about

```
auto ProfilerRun(T&& func, const std::string&) -> decltype(T()))
```

but in this case `decltype` will call `T`'s constructor when a function object is delivered. Is there any possible strategies to solve this problem?

Comment: `decltype(func())` would do, btw.

Comment: @Fernades Good point, I have not noticed this.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got the answer:

```
#include <type_traits>

typename std::result_of<T()>::type ProfilerRun(T&&, const std::string&);
```

will work.